# Why a submanifold is an open subset of its closure?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, submanifold

When I am reading *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras I* by Onishchik, I come across the claim that "As any submanifold, a Lie subgroup is an open subset of its closure." From this the author deduces that all cosets of the subgroup is open. Why is the quoted claim true? Also, why does a Lie subgroup being open in its closure imply a Lie subgroup is open in the entire Lie group?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? man this is interesting

Comment: Is that really the author's conclusion? Most Lie subgroups aren't open, since a neighbourhood of the identity generates the group (for a concrete example, think about $S^1 \times \{e\}$ inside the torus).

Comment: You should add a precise reference to the place in the book where this strange claim is coming from. My guess is that the subgroup is assumed to be the component of identity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan that can't possibly be that simple. Connected components are always closed. And so the statement is trivially true.

Comment: @freakish: For Lie groups, they are also open. The book is about Lie groups, so, possibly, this is what is discussed. Regardless, the context is important when analyzing this claim.

Comment: I think, the claim should be read as: Let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of a Lie group $G$ (where Lie subgroups are assumed to be embedded submanifolds). Then $H$ is open in $cl(H)$ with respect to the subspace topology on $cl(H)$. This is definitely true.

Comment: It looks like they do really say that - it's on the bottom of page 8 of the book, and the upshot of the paragraph is that any Lie subgroup is closed. Actually, maybe what they mean is: 1) the subgroup $H$ is open in its closure; 2) the closure of $H$ *is itself a subgroup* of $G$; and 3) since an open subgroup is closed, $H$ must equal its closure. Point 2) is confusingly not mentioned in that paragraph in the book.

Comment: @AlexK: Then it is just sloppy language on their part, they forgot to mention several things.

Comment: @MoisheKohan God bless you for fighting for the little guy.

Comment: @AlexK God bless you for fighting for the little guy.

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand something but from my perspective it looks like actually the opposite is true. Even in more general, topological case. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is not closed then it is also not open in $\overline{H}$. In particular the statement is only true when $H$ is closed to begin with, which makes it trivially true.

> **Lemma 1.** If $H$ is a subgroup of a topological group $G$ with a nonempty interior then $H$ is clopen.

*Proof.* Let $U\subseteq H$ be a nonempty open subset. Given $h\in U$ we get that $e\in h^{-1}U$ and still $h^{-1}U\subseteq H$. And so WLOG we may assume that $e\in U$. But then $H=\bigcup_{h\in H}hU$ making $H$ open. On the other hand $G-H=\bigcup_{h\in G-H}hU$ (because cosets partition $G$) and so $G-H$ is open as well making $H$ closed. $\Box$

> **Lemma 2.** If $H$ is a subgroup of a topological group $G$ then $\overline{H}$ is a subgroup as well.

*Proof.* Let $a,b\in\overline{H}$. Let $W$ be a neighbourhood of $ab^{-1}$. Consider $f:G\times G\to G$, $f(x,y)=xy^{-1}$. By the continuity of $f$ and the definition of product topology there is open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ and open neighbourhood $V$ of $b$ such that $U\times V\subseteq f^{-1}(W)$. But then $U\cap H\neq\emptyset$ and $V\cap H\neq \emptyset$ since $a,b\in\overline{H}$. Let $x\in U\cap H$ and $y\in V\cap H$. It follows that $xy^{-1}\in W\cap H$, and so $W\cap H\neq\emptyset$. By the arbitrary choice of $W$ we get that $ab^{-1}\in\overline{H}$. $\Box$

---

Both lemmas applied imply that if a subgroup $H$ is open in $\overline{H}$ then $H$ is also closed and thus $H=\overline{H}$. In particular if $H$ is not closed then it is never open in $\overline{H}$.

Comment: In the same paragraph that OP is talking about, Onishchik goes "As any submanifold, a Lie subgroup is an open subset of its closure. However, any open subgroup of a topological group is at the same time closed, since it is the complement of the union of its own cosets, which, like the subgroup itself, are open subsets. Hence any Lie subgroup is closed."

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a topological space. A set $A\subset X$ is open in its closure if and only if for every $a\in A$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ in $X$ such that the intersection $A\cap U$ is closed in $U$. I know this property by the name "locally closed".

We will need the reverse implication, which for completeness we can prove like this. For $a\in A$, pick a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ in $X$ as in the definition. Then $A\cap U$ is actually open in $\bar A$ - indeed, $A\cap U$ is equal to its closure in $U$, which is $\bar A \cap U$ (since any closed set in $U$ is of the form $F\cap U$ for $F$ closed in $X$). This proves that a neighbourhood of $a$ in $\bar A$ is completely contained in $A$, as needed.

Consider now a smooth manifold $M$ and a(n embedded) submanifold $S$. Then every $s\in S$ has a coordinate neighbourhood $U$ with the property that $S\cap U$ is given by the vanishing of a subset of the coordinates - in particular, $S\cap U$ is closed in $U$. This means that $S$ is locally closed, and so it's open in its closure.

Finally, let's consider the case of a Lie group $G$ and a Lie subgroup $H$. The upshot of the paragraph cited in the question is that $H$ must be closed in $G$. We verify this by showing $H = \bar H$. As $H$ is a submanifold of $G$, it is open in $\bar H$. On the other hand, $\bar H$ is itself a subgroup of $G$. Indeed, if $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ are sequences in $H$ convergent to $x,y$ respectively, then continuity of multiplication implies that $(x_i y_i)$ converges to $xy$, which is therefore in $\bar H$. Similar considerations hold for the inverse.

This means we have that $H$ is an open subgroup of $\bar H$. Since translation by an element is a homeomorphism, each coset of $H$ is also open in $\bar H$. Since $H$ is the complement in $\bar H$ of its nontrivial cosets, it is closed. But this means that $H = \bar H$, as claimed.